# update table with php arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
Array (     [3] => 40000     [5] => 20300     [17] => 29000     
[4] => 35000     [6] => 59000     [54] =>      [34] =>      [7] => 113000     
[55] =>      [35] =>      [8] => 219000     [56] =>      [36] =>      [9] => 40600      )
```

array `keys = id`

array `values = price`

I want update table with this values and when the price is exist, save the price and when the price is not exist, save the "NULL"

Here my code:

```
<form method="post">
    <?php
    $qr2=$mysqli->query("SELECT `price`,`id` FROM `pricing`");
    while($row2=$qr2->fetch_object()){
    ?>
    <input type="text" class="nw-prc" value="<?php echo $row2->price; ?>" name="price[<?php echo $row2->id; ?>]">
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</form>
<input type="submit" id="up" name="up" value="save">

<?php
if (isset($_POST['up'])) {
    $price=$_POST['price'];
}

$keys=array_keys($price);
$values=array_values($price);

foreach($keys as $k){
    foreach($values as $v){
        $mysqli->query("UPDATE `pricing` SET `price`='$v' WHERE `id`='$k'");
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Can you `print_r($_POST)` to see what is the result we get?

Comment: **What error you are getting ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
foreach($your_array as $key => $value){
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE `pricing` SET `price`='$value' WHERE `id`='$key'");
}
```

instead of

```
 foreach($keys as $k){
    foreach($values as $v){
        $mysqli->query("UPDATE `pricing` SET `price`='$v' WHERE `id`='$k'");
     }

}
```